# Change assets directory or load assets from other dir to default dir at runtime

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have 3 different android builds(exported from Unity 3D); I want to trigger them from a single android app. Unity 3D creates asset bundles and splits them into 1MB files(.split(n));i cannot combine all assets in the data directory as they get over written and there is no way to determine which file contains what asset.

So I have created 3 folders in data viz. 1,2,3 and would like to load the assets from these directories at runtime (onClick).

I would like to know if there is a way of doing this or is there another solution for this problem ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that "asset bundles" are a specific Unity feature that you don't appear to be using. Ironically, they're partly designed to solve this exact sort of problem.

Comment: ok, i will look into it; thanks...but does it work for multiple simulations

Comment: i did look into it, but the problem persists...i am still getting a list of .split(n) files which are same across projects